# Control the color of contours

Tags: plotting

I use `ContourPlot` frequently and sometimes the contours are not easily discerned because most values are small with a few very big ones. When I use `FuchsiaTones`, only the peak is visible and the rest is black.

Can I somehow define the color of the contour lines? For example, using `FuchsiaTones`, but converted so the peak has dark contour lines and the rest has light colored lines?

Comment: Have you considered plotting a `ContourPlot` in log scale, that is, plotting the log of your data?

Comment: yes I thought about it, but I think it is better to plot it with a normal scale

Comment: How do you expect anyone to answer this without any idea of what function you are plotting nor what that function's domain is?

Comment: I think this could be done with any function. My function is quite complictated and runs a while.

Comment: It is a good idea to provide a minimal example with a simple function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume that you are obtaining a plot looking something like this.

```
ContourPlot[Exp[1/(x^2 + y^2 + 1/4)], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "FuchsiaTones"]
```

[image]

To have the dark countour regions at the peak, use

```
ContourPlot[Exp[1/(x^2 + y^2 + 1/4)], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"FuchsiaTones", "Reverse"}][#] &)]
```

[image]

Simpler yet is the suggestion by [ybeltukov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4678/ybeltukov).

```
ContourPlot[Exp[1/(x^2 + y^2 + 1/4)], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
    ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"FuchsiaTones", "Reverse"}]]
```

which produces the same result.

Comment: In the last example you can simply use `ColorData[{"FuchsiaTones", "Reverse"}]`

Comment: @ybeltukov  Indeed, so.  Thanks.  With your permission, I shall add it to my answer.

Comment: Yes, of course, there is no copyright on this small note.

Comment: my idea was it to convert the color of the contours but this should work aswell